# How do I create a localdb in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Till now, whenever I wanted to create a local sql database in visual studio, I'd fire it up, run the default page and try to log in. This would create it automatically. I just downloaded Community version 2015 and it is not creating a database, though it did create a connection string in the web.config

Answer (score 2):

In my installation the SQL stuff was not installed by default. Maybe that's the case for you, too?
Regard, Klaus

Answer (score 0):

You need install `LocalDB 64BIT\SqlLocalDB.msi` from [Microsoft's page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=42299). Here's a [tutorial about the localdb connection](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QK4Z1NYh6YU)

Open CMD and RUN this comand `sqllocaldb info` you need see (v12.0) if not, run this command:

```
sqllocaldb create "v12.0"
```